# JButton Only Works When Visibility is Set to True-Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, visibility, static-methods

I am trying to make a simple checkers game basically, and I need the user to only be able to see the tiles and the pieces, not the button. When I set the visibility to True, the program works by giving me a test message of "Hey a button was pressed!" However, when I set the visibility to False (what I need it to be), I no longer get the test message. The only forum question I seen related to this from a general google search was to use repaint and revalidate, but those did not work and thus I removed those 2 lines of code. I normally would have a button class that would work great, but due to my code only accepting static and not normal, I have to implement jbutton directly in my main class. So what is wrong exactly? Here is my code and thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CheckersMain extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    private static JFrame window;
    private static Color winBackground=Color.GRAY;
    private static Color tile1Color=Color.WHITE;
    private static Color tile2Color=Color.BLACK;
    private static int windowWidth=1000;
    private static int windowHeight=1000;
    private static int setScreenLoc=500;
    private static int tileDimention=100;
    private static Board board;
    private static ArrayList<JButton> allButtons=new ArrayList<JButton>();
    private static ArrayList<Tile> allTiles;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window=new JFrame();
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("Checkers");
        window.setLocation(setScreenLoc,setScreenLoc);
        window.setSize(windowWidth,windowHeight);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(winBackground);
        window.setVisible(true);
        board=new Board(window,tileDimention,tile1Color,tile2Color);
        allTiles=board.setUp();
        setUpButtons();
        window.repaint();
    }

    private static void setUpButtons() {
        for (int i=0;i<allTiles.size();++i) {
            Tile currentTile=allTiles.get(i);
            JButton button=new JButton();
            button.setSize(tileDimention,tileDimention);
            button.setLocation(currentTile.getXlocation(),currentTile.getYlocation());
            window.add(button,0);
            button.addActionListener(new CheckersMain());
            button.setVisible(false);
            allButtons.add(button);
        }
    }

    private void buttonPressed() {
        System.out.println("Hey a button was pressed!");
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent frame) {
        for (int i=0;i<allButtons.size();++i) {
            if (frame.getSource()==allButtons.get(i)) {
                buttonPressed();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the button is invisible (ie hidden), why would you expect to get the message?  How would the user click it?

Comment: The button is really there behind the scenes, the user just cant see it. The user would click in without knowing essentially.

Comment: *The button is really there behind the scenes* That is not what "visible" means in Java. In Java, if the component is not visible it is not painted; and if it is not painted it really is **not** there.

Comment: Okay, so visibility is kind of like a button (no pun intended) where you can turn it on and off. So my solution is to set up the buttons first with visibility set to true of course, and then go on with setting up the board?

Comment: "visibility" determines if the button is shown on the UI or not. If it is hidden, it can't be interacted with and in some cases the layout managers will ignore them and the layout will change accordingly

Comment: Well they should probably change that method to setSwitchState or something like that. Anyways, thanks. I guess I will have to set up the buttons before the board with the pieces, a little bit burdensome but can work with that. Or I could use the mouse listener interface maybe.

Comment: *"where you can turn it on and off"* Use a `JToggleButton`. It represents the 'path of least surprise' for the user.

Comment: To Andrew, that part wasn't a question. I was explaining my understanding of it. And the togglebutton wouldn't solve my issue as I need the button to work but not be visible, so I need to put the buttons up first then the actual image I want after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good place to use the Glass Pane:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

The glass pane is invisible, but still receives mouse move and click events. Add a click listener on the glass pane and get the mouse position, then check if that position is over the space where your 'hidden' button would be.